# Vaadin UIScope import does not compile

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

I have a problem with `@UIScope` annotation in vaadin 8.9.0. Here is some snippet:

```
package com.negdoor;

import com.vaadin.flow.spring.annotation.SpringComponent;
import com.vaadin.flow.spring.annotation.UIScope;
import com.vaadin.server.Page;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;

@UIScope
@SpringComponent
public class Current {

    private UI ui;

    public void set(UI ui) {
        this.setUi(ui);
    }

    public Page getPage() {
        Page result = null;
        if (ui != null)
            result = ui.getPage();
        return result;
    }

    public UI getUi() {
        return ui;
    }

    public void setUi(UI ui) {
        this.ui = ui;
    }

}
```

The result is: 
[image]

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are importing Vaadin Spring add-on version 12.x whily you should use version 3.2.1 with Vaadin 8.9.0.

Comment: I solved my problem it was my internet connection. Maven dependencies download failed. Re download maven fixed my problems. Btw thank you.